# Parsing result from async Sharepoint list query in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, odata

I'm using Javascript to summarise data from a sharepoint list. I've got the query working and returning OK, and i can see from the console that it is returning everything I need, however I cannot work out how to parse it.

`jQuery.fromJSON` returns an error, as does the significant number of other things i've tried. Other than doing some regex or something i'm at a loss.

Can anyone suggest how this type of sharepoint response can be parsed so i can use the objects/data in each row.

Thanks

```
function GetProductInformation(){
                var query = '<View><Query><Where> <And><Geq><FieldRef Name="Data_x0020_Due_x0020_Date"/><Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2017-07-01</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="Data_x0020_Due_x0020_Date"/><Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2018-06-29</Value></Leq></And> </Where><GroupBy Collapse="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="Analyser"/></GroupBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Analyser"/><FieldRef Name="Number_x0020_of_x0020_products"/></ViewFields><Aggregations Value="On"><FieldRef Name="Number_x0020_of_x0020_products" Type ="SUM"/></Aggregations></View>';


                console.log("Query is " + query);   

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Work tracker - Products');

    console.log("GetProductInformation Async Request") 

    jsonResult = oList.renderListData(query);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetProductQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGetProductQueryFailed));        
                //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onGetProductQuerySucceeded, onGetProductQueryFailed);
                console.log("GetProductInformation Async Requested")     
}


function onGetProductQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
                console.log('Query Success');
                var dataFromYou = jsonResult
                console.log(dataFromYou);

                var data = dataFromYou.Row[0]; //This bit doesn't work
                console.log(data)
```

Find below some example output:

```
"{ "Row" : 
[{
"Analyser": [{"lookupId":1,"lookupValue":"Accounts Payable 
Analyser","isSecretFieldValue":false}],
"Analyser.urlencoded": "%3B%23Accounts%20Payable%20Analyser%3B%23",
"Analyser.COUNT.group": "363",
"Analyser.newgroup": "1",
"Analyser.groupindex": "1_",
"Number_x0020_of_x0020_products.SUM": "14,694",
"Number_x0020_of_x0020_products.SUM.agg": "658"
}
,{
"Analyser": [{"lookupId":2,"lookupValue":"Accounts Receivable 
Analyser","isSecretFieldValue":false}],
"Analyser.urlencoded": "%3B%23Accounts%20Receivable%20Analyser%3B%23",
```

Comment: Does `JSON.parse(dataFromYou)` not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example:

```
var result = list.renderListData(qry.get_viewXml());
```

[`SP.List.renderListData` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247244.aspx) returns [`SP.Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff411273(v=office.14).aspx) object and the list data could be retrieved like this:

```
var listData = result.get_value();
```

Since the list data is returned as a JSON string it could be easily parsed like this:

```
var jsonVal = JSON.parse(result.get_value());
if(jsonVal.Row.length > 0)
    console.log(jsonVal.Row[0]);   //get first row data
```

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var qry = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
var result = list.renderListData(qry.get_viewXml());

ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
       var jsonVal = JSON.parse(result.get_value());
       if(jsonVal.Row.length > 0)
           console.log(jsonVal.Row[0]);
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message()); 
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

I found solution for same problem by using:

```
var results = JSON.parse(data.d.RenderListData).Row;
```

This gives me an array of returned listdata objects.